# React onChange não esta disparando

Tags: jquery, react, callback

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
handleChange(event, module) {
    this.state[module][event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
    const handleChange = (event, module) => {
        this.handleChange(event, module);
    }    
    return (
        <form ref="steps" action="#" className="wizard-big" id="paymentForm">
            <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel htmlFor="bank_account_agency">Agência</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl name="bank_account_agency" id="bank_account_agency" type="text" value={this.state.bank.bank_account_agency} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "bank")} required />
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel htmlFor="bank_account_number">Conta</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl name="bank_account_number" id="bank_account_number" type="text" value={this.state.bank.bank_account_number} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "bank")} required />
            </FormGroup>
        </form>
  );
}
```

O `onChange` não é disparado em nenhum `input` dentro do `form`, eu testei fora dele e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Estou utilizando a biblioteca [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) e creio que seja esse o problema, porém não consigo encontrar o motivo do erro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de fazer métodos dentro de uma classe com `fat arrows`, daí eu nunca preciso de colocar o `.bind()`

Você pode remover a função dentro do seu `render()`

Eu coloquei: `constructor` e umas variáveis dentro do `render` para poder mostrar o exemplo, e removi os componentes do "Bootstrap" também

```js
//import React from 'react';

class Formulario extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { bank: {} };
  }
  //fat arrow functions não precisam de dar o .bind
  handleChange = (event, module) => {   
      this.state[module][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
      let baa = this.state.bank.bank_account_agency ? this.state.bank.bank_account_agency : null;
      let ban = this.state.bank.bank_account_number ? this.state.bank.bank_account_number : null;
      return (
        <form ref="steps" action="#" className="wizard-big" id="paymentForm">
            <h1>Bank account agency: <span class={"agency"}>{ baa }</span></h1>
            <h1>Bank account number: <span class={"number"}>{ ban }</span></h1>
            <input onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, "bank")} name={"bank_account_agency"}/>
            <input onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, "bank")} name={"bank_account_number"}/>
        </form>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Formulario/>, document.querySelector(".root"));
```

```html
<div class="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Só é possível atualizar o state do React com this.setState você NUNCA deve alterar o this.state diretamente. Pois é com o this.state que o React vai vai saber o que mudou ou não. Você iniciou o componente sem state inicial, logo deve usar this.setState para definir novos valores.